# Handling empty arrays with foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

```
$foo = '';

foreach((array)$foo as $f){
  echo 'xxx';
}
```

Will still output 'xxx'...

Comment: have you tried `$foo=array();` instead of an empty string?

Comment: because (array)$foo creates an array with one empty string item - $foo = array("")

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Casting an empty string to an array won't result in an empty array. It will create an array with an empty string as an item:

```
array(
    0 => ''
)
```

You could check if it's a valid array:

```
if(is_array($foo))
{
    foreach($foo as $f)
    {
        echo 'xxx';
    }
}
```

Comment: No you don't, casting is enough!

Comment: You must have seen another answer… the only check probably needed is the one for emptiness, but not the check for if it is an array. See the (correct) answer from @Subdigger.

Comment: I don't think that his answer is corrent, because $foo = 'awesome' is not empty but also not an array!

Comment: @Martin to answer to some question at least it should be clear. But when someone asking question like this `2 + 2 = ?` and in question he tells that `you know I have a calculator and I have tried 2 + 1 and get 3 as an answer`. The only correct answer is tell him that he do something wrong.

Answer (score 10):

`(array)$foo`:

This is not empty array, but array which contains an empty element.

Comment: Exactly: `array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(0) ""
}`

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it will output 'XXX', because the string variable `$foo = ''` converted to array will become:

```
array(
    0 => ''
)
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you are not creating an empty array by type casting the following statement. The below code would actually produce an array with an empty string in its first element.

```
$foo = '';
(array)$foo;
```

So, the correct way, to create an empty array is

```
$foo = array();
foreach($foo as $f){
   echo 'xxx';
}
```

Hope, this helps you ...

Answer (score 1):

```
if(!empty($foo))
    foreach((array)$foo as $f)
    {
      echo 'xxx';
    }
```

Comment: $foo = 'I am a string'; would be a problem here.

Comment: @Martin Bieder i think not. because of (array)$foo. and because of i ts not my code. i don't care if someone do not check if his array is array. the problem was _Will still output 'xxx'..._ and the given code resolv this problem

Comment: $var = (array) 'string'; would return an array with an element 'string'. In that specific excerp you're right, but I would always check if it's an array before looping through it.

Comment: @Martin Bieder so and i. but the man wants this to be a string. see the question.

Comment: you cannot read it in his description. He just described the general scenario.

Answer (score 1):

I always check for type and contents before I perform a foreach. E.g.

```
if( is_array($foo) && sizeof($foo) <> 0)
{
 // do foreach
}
```